# Clicking an element for Chrome browser an issue when using selenium automation?

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, testing, automation

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button")).click();

expected result: Successfully clicked button.

actual result: Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element must be displayed to click (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information);".

Comment: What do you mean this is an issue for Chrome browser while exception clearly says that element must be displayed to click..so before clicking you need to check `isDisplayed()` returns true or false...

Comment: Like others mentioned already, please check that the button is visible manually (by your eyes). If it is not visible, then do something to make it visible before you click it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check `isDisplayed()` and `isEnabled()`  before click as below :-

```
WebElement el = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button"));
if(el.isDisplayed() && el.isEnabled())
{
   el.click();
}
```

Or you should try using `WebDriverWait` with `ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable` as below :-

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement el = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button")));
el.click();
```

**Note** :- `elementToBeClickable` is used for checking an element is visible and enabled such that you can click it.

`WebDriverWait` with`ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable` returns `WebElement` if expected condition is true otherwise it will throw `TimeoutException`

Hope it helps...:)